# Using inline variables in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, inline-variable

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and I tried to declare this in my header file:

```
inline static int counter{1};
```

Now VS underlines it red and tells me that 'inline' can only be used for functions, although it should be possible since C++17.

Is there a way to still use it in VS or do I have to work around?

Comment: What version of MSVS are you using?  Did you set the standard setting to C++17 or latest?

Comment: Are you confusing VS 2017 with proposed c++17?

Comment: Apparently it is not supported by VS2017 yet, even if it is set to C++17 mode.

Comment: @user0042 strike that "proposed" -- C++17 is live :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Nov. 15, 2017, inline variables are scheduled to be supported in Visual Studio 15.5.  You can see the "current" status of features [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/)
 or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) .